# Collect similar objects in ArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method which collects all objects from an ArrayList, and then adds up the similar object creating a name and amount map, of sorts. I would like the method to be able to check the type, name and hp, and if all are the same, amount should be incremented and perhaps delete the other one? After this it is supposed to represented in JavaFX GUI in an observablelist.

The objects in this example is units from a simulation, in which the 8 represented in the photo, should be showed as:
Type: InfantryUnit,
Name: Test,
HP: 10
Amount: 8.

[JavaFX GUI for representing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHfqk.png)

I have attempted a few solutions, but with no avail. I expect a map of sorts will be necessary but have not found a good way to collect and display the amount of units. Also while also retrieving the amount of units to actually be used to simulate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:
Units class is a super class to 4 subtypes: Infantry, ranged, cavalry and commander(Subtype of cavalry).

```
public abstract class Unit implements Bonuses {
    private String name;

    private int health; //Total health, means the unit can take more damage before dying.
    private int attack; //Attack value to decide how much health each attack does.
    private int armor; //Defense value to decide resistance to attacks.

    private boolean isAlive; //Boolean which tells if a unit is dead or alive.
    private int hitsDealt; //Count hits dealt.
    private int hitsTaken; //Count hits received.
    private String className; //The type of unit, infantry/ranged etc.
    private terrain terrain; //Enum terrain from bonus interface.

    public Unit(String name, int health, int attack, int armor) {
        setName(name);
        setHealth(health);
        this.attack = attack;
        this.armor = armor;
        className = getClass().getSimpleName();
        hitsDealt = 0;
        hitsTaken = 0;
    }
```

Army class is just meant to represent a list of units as such. This is the place i'd like to implement the method mentioned above.

```
public class Army {
    private String name;
    private List<Unit> units;
    private Random randomUnit;

    /**
     * Constructor of the army class.
     *
     * @param name Name of army.
     */
    public Army(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        units = new ArrayList<>();
        this.randomUnit = new Random();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiSet`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiSet.html) and its `getCount`, it probably fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

This uses toString() as key, in which the toString() contains unitType, name and health. Then it checks if the map contains such a key, if not it puts a new one in. If it exist then it adds it to a list connected to the key.

```
/**
     * Method to collect same units into map.
     * Used to display amount of units in GUI.
     * @return Map of string and a list of units connected to said string.
     */
    public Map<String, List<Unit>> getSortedList() {
        HashMap<String, List<Unit>> sortedUnits = new HashMap<>();

        for (Unit u : units) {
            if (sortedUnits.containsKey(u.toString())) {
                sortedUnits.get(u.toString()).add(u);
            } else {
                List<Unit> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(u);
                sortedUnits.put(u.toString(), list);
            }
        }

        return sortedUnits;
    }
```

This method works as the list connected to the toString() key could be checked with list.size().